# Dynamically generate Goldberg polyhedra G(m,n)

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra, geometric-construction, geodesic

In these pages the author provided a lot of info about some Goldberg polyhedra (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron):

- http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/DualGeodesicIcosahedra.html
- http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/DualGeodesicIcosahedraPage2.html

Unfortunately the Java applets doesn't work anymore. But, for any of these polyhedra it's still possible to get some info, e.g. for the G(3,2):

- http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/DualGeodesicIcosahedron8.html
- http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/DualGeodesicIcosahedron8.txt

I'd like to dynamically generate, given ANY "m" and "n", those info about G(m,n):

- Edge lengths
- Number of edge of the same length
- A list of constants
- A list of vertexes defined using the constants
- A list of faces defined using the vertexes

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this helps: http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10wC and for the java stuff, it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/6nybd7/is_there_a_plugin_for_making_goldberg_polyhedra/) Reddit thread I found [antiprism](http://antiprism.com/download/index.html) which seems to do just that. Once installed, try `geodesic -c 1,3 ico > test.off` which will generate an (m,n)=(1,3) polyhedron. It can be visualized by `antiview test.off`.